# HTML Form Refreshes When I Click "Submit" Button

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

The PHP script doesn't even run. When I click 'submit', it simply refreshes the page. I even tested the code without the action on the form and it did the same. I tried using both button and input for the submit button. Both don't work.

Here is the form code:

```
                        <form name="input" action="oakmanagement.com/SendEmployeeApplication.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <!-- middle -->
    <td style="width: 12px">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <!-- for multiple images use the rel=gallery[mygallery]
            <tr>
                <td><a href="http://www.expressionofjoy.com/outreach/images/sm/Event_0000s_0008_Layer-5.jpg" class="lightview" rel="gallery[mygallery]" title="my caption"><img src="/images/photoGalleryHolder.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
            </tr>
            -->
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" height="10px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" height="10px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><br /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </td>
    <!-- spacing, do not touch -->
    <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="10px" /></td>
    <!-- right -->
    <td class="tdRightColumnTemplate">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="txtXLargeBlack">Oak Management Employment - SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTION!</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" height="20px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
              <!-- form -->

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" height="20px" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    <!-- /A head + field -->    
                    <!-- Personal header -->

                        <tr><td colspan="2" bgcolor="#cdd0bd">
                        <!-- <input type="Hidden" value="" name="PERSONAL_SECTION" /> -->
                    <b class="txtNormalBlack" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">Personal:</b>
                        </td></tr>

                    <!-- /A head + field -->    
                    <!-- head + field -->

                        <tr><td colspan="2">
                        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="left" style="background-color: #dddddd; height: 200px;">
                            <tr>

                                <td align="left" id="t_fname" class="formFields">First</td>
                                <td align="left" class="formFields">Middle</td>
                                <td align="left" id="t_lname" class="formFields">Last Name</td>

                                <td align="left" id="t_email" class="formFields">E&#45;mail</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="formFields">    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="FIRST_NAME" VALUE="" SIZE="15" MAXLENGTH="30"> 
                                </td><td align="left" class="formFields">   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="MIDDLE_NAME" VALUE="" SIZE="15" MAXLENGTH="30">
                                </td><td align="left" class="formFields">   <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="LAST_NAME" VALUE="" SIZE="15" MAXLENGTH="30">
                                </td><td class="formFields"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="EMAIL" VALUE="" SIZE="20" MAXLENGTH="60"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                                <td class="formFields" align="center" colspan="2">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                                <input type="reset" name="RESET" value="Reset" class="btnform" />
                                </td>  
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td></tr>

                    </table> 

                <!-- end of form -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" height="20px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

  </td>
</tr>
```

> Here's the PHP:

```
function sendEmailToCompany() {
    $from = stripslashes($_POST['EMAIL']);
    $to = "mymail@mail.com";
    $subject = "Employment Form For " . stripslashes($_POST['FIRST_NAME']);
    $message = "Personal\n\nFirst Name: " . stripslashes($_POST['FIRST_NAME']) . "
                \nMiddle Name: " . stripslashes($_POST["MIDDLE_NAME"]) . "
                \nLast Name: " . stripslashes($_POST['LAST_NAME']) . "
                \nE-mail: " . stripslashes($_POST['EMAIL']);
}
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
sendEmailToCompany();
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=ThankYou.aspx'>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide your PHP please. There's seemingly nothing wrong with your HTML so perhaps your PHP is redirecting you back to this page?

Comment: I'll add it to the main post.

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with the PHP. The submit button doesn't even run the PHP.

Answer (score 4):

You have `<form><tr>`: this is not allowed. A form cannot contain *part* of a table. Either the form must be contained entirely within in a single cell or the whole table must be in the form.

Your browser is probably error correcting (error recovery for this error is not consistent across all browsers) by closing it before the table row starts or by moving the form so it appears after the table (leaving the controls behind).

When you click the submit button, you aren't submitting the form.

[Validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML to avoid this sort of problem.

[image: Screenshot of closed form in DOM inspector]

Comment: Sorry - I have the form inside of a table. I editted the code to show the entire table.

Comment: I would disagree. Firstly, the form *is* submitting, secondly, it's only the rendering of the page that makes elements appear after a table, not the order of the DOM. **Although** yeah, it should be outside the table and this is indeed invalid markup.

Comment: @user1913362, what Quentin is saying is that `<form name="input" action="oakmanagement.com/SendEmployeeApplication.php" method="post">` should be outside of your `<table>`.

Comment: @user1913362 — After your edit, you still have the form attempting to be a child element of the table and a parent element of a tr. That is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually sending the the mail, may be why it's not working! You are preparing all of the data but not putting it throught the mail function.

```
function sendEmailToCompany() {
$from = stripslashes($_POST['EMAIL']);
$to = "mymail@mail.com";
$subject = "Employment Form For " . stripslashes($_POST['FIRST_NAME']);
$message = "Personal\n\nFirst Name: " . stripslashes($_POST['FIRST_NAME']) . "
            \nMiddle Name: " . stripslashes($_POST["MIDDLE_NAME"]) . "
            \nLast Name: " . stripslashes($_POST['LAST_NAME']) . "
            \nE-mail: " . stripslashes($_POST['EMAIL']);
// PART I HAVE ADDED...
mail($to, $subject, $message, $from);
// -------------------

}
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
sendEmailToCompany();
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=ThankYou.aspx'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code on this part :

`echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=ThankYou.aspx'>";`

that will bring you redirect to page **ThankYou.aspx**

Change the url param wich the same type PHP

It would be better if you give conditional, so you can check whether the email sent is perfect or not

```
if(sendEmailToCompany())
{
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=ThankYou.php'>";
   //true condition
}
else
{
  echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

**Replace**

```
<button type="submit">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
```

**With**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**And replace**

```
 <form name="employment" action="./SendEmployeeApplication.php" method="post">
```

**With**

```
 <form name="employment" action="YOURDIRECTORY/SendEmployeeApplication.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference? I don't understand why anyone would upvote this as it makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: @user1913362 Edit the post with the **PHP code ofSendEmployeeApplication.php** , because when I try the script that you have gave me it redirects me to SendEmployeeApplication.php The problem might be you're PHP script